# How to create a list within a list of duplicate files?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a section of code that creates a list of raster files within a directory:

```
import arcpy, os

workspace = r'C:\temp'

# Get a list of all files in all subfolders
rasters = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace,
                                                  topdown = True,
                                                  datatype="RasterDataset"):
    for filename in filenames:
        rasters.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```

Which produces a list of .tif files:

```
[r'C:\temp\block1\fileA.tif', r'C:\temp\block1\fileB.tif', r'C:\temp\block2\fileA.tif', r'C:\temp\block2\fileB.tif']
```

How can I generate a list of lists that contain duplicate file names, like the following example?

```
[[r'C:\temp\block1\fileA.tif', r'C:\temp\block2\fileA.tif'], [r'C:\temp\block1\fileB.tif', r'C:\temp\block2\fileB.tif']]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collect files in a dictionary, keyed by the base name; a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) makes this easier:

```
from collections import defaultdict

rasters = defaultdict(list)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace,
                                                  topdown = True,
                                                  datatype="RasterDataset"):
    for filename in filenames:
        rasters[filename].append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

rasters = rasters.values()
```

This groups paths by `filename` into lists; `rasters.values()` builds your desired list-of-lists.